# Excel - Calculate a Cell only if it is not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Overview**
[image: Overview]

**Formulas**

[image: Formulas]

Below are the formulas for these cells, it may not be formatted perfectly but should convey the message.

```
Item    Buy Price   Price Increase %    Margin %    Margin $    Sell Price   Term     %             Price    Final Price   Associated Equipment Tag     Item          Cost
Fan     100         0.1                 0.2         =I3-E3      =E3/(1-G3)   10       =J3*0.002    =I3*K3     =I3+L3       =IF(C3="","",C3)        =IF(D3="","",D3)   =IF(M3="","",M3)
```

I have a estimating/cost tracking excel sheet that i am looking to build a percentage increase column in here to cover any future cost increases.  I want to keep the columns to a minimum so it can still be printed on a regular sheet of paper.  The last 3 columns are what we copy and paste into the proposal that is sent to the client.

What I am trying to do is put the initial buy price into the document, then if the need arises I can input a "Price Increase %" lets say 8.5% and then the "Margin %" will be calculated on the new increased percentage added to the "buy price" not the original "Buy Price".  I want to modify the original buy price because just adding more margin is not a precise way of doing business.

I have included my formulas as well, any advice, suggestions, or improvements would be greatly appreciated.

I think i could make it work by adding a few columns but this still would have to be figured out in the last 3 columns which I copy and paste into the proposal that makes it off to the client.

I tried a few nested if and isblank statements but nothing that would really work.

Comment: Can you show your formulae in text format?

Comment: IF(A1="","",A1) is a classic structure to not calculate with blanks.

Comment: I tried to format the code in there and it just looks like a paragraph, do you just need me to place the formulas in here so you can copy and paste?

Comment: You can put the formula in code tags.

Comment: Added the formulas in code tags.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should i change the title of this question? I feel like I might not be getting answers because the title is unclear.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions for this answer? Almost no one has looked at this question, how do i change that? any suggestions?